# jQuery plugin for generating multi coloured text which changes colour on hover

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, fonts, hover

I would like to generate multicoloured text for various links, with a random assignment of colours to individual letters, from a pre-specified array of colours, which would change on hovering over the div with the text in.  I am thinking a jQuery plugin/script would be the way to go.

I am wondering if such a plugin, or a close approximation, exists.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i whip up an example using jquery.

first your text

```
<p id="example">Multi color me</p>​
```

then the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var test = $("#example").text().split('');

    var result = "";
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i < test.length; i++) {
        result += "<span style='color:"+getColor()+"'>"+test[i]+"</span>";
    }
    $("#example").html(result);      
});

function getColor() {
    var colList = ['#00FF00', '#FF0000','#0000FF'];

    var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*colList.length));
  return colList[i];
}​
```

Heres the jsFiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DZpyw/1/)

Note: i did not do the hover but I guessing you can take it from here :)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm after.  For some strange reason a test page that I created with just your code in isn't working though.  You can see it [here](http://monthlymixup.com/test.html). Hoping I haven't done something dumb.

Comment: Try putting the script in the header instead of body

Comment: oh and i believe i missed a semi-colon at end of `result +=`

Comment: Thanks. i tried it in the header first and this didn't work.  It's now back in the header.

Comment: Inclusion of semi-colon also doesn't fix it for me.

Comment: Hmm ok well i downloaded at your right it failed so i went to see why it worked in jsfiddle and it seems they wrap extra round it. see [showFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DZpyw/1/show/)

Comment: Ok what does it have to do on hover as each letter has a different color and you will need to remember that color so it can return to it after hovering. Jquery provides .data() to set and get data against a element and events mouseenter and mouseleave should give you the hover effect. if this awnsers it please dont forget to accept :)

Comment: On hover I would simply like it to randomise the colours again from the array.  Ideally it would go back to the original colours on leaving the div, but if that's not possible it could simply randomise the colours again.  I think this might stump me so any further pointers would be helpful! Thanks.

Comment: ok this should make that happen [jsfiddleUpdate](http://jsfiddle.net/DZpyw/14/), i turned the generator into a function and ran it twice storing the result then i switched between each as i go.

Comment: Thanks - I was working on adding the mouseenter and mouseout events, but it would probably have taken me some time to get there! I have added your new script, wrapped in window load function, and it isn't working at my end, as you can see [here](http://monthlymixup.com/test.html). Also, on the fiddle only the mouseenter event is working.

Comment: ok [updated again](http://jsfiddle.net/DZpyw/17/) i added a timeout as mouseout works if you leave a certain way (at least in chrome). i downloaded it as well as you example and tested and it worked (although i couldn't test the font obviously)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it's still not working for me. Can one download a jsFiddle then, for testing elsewhere?

Comment: i just went to [show](http://jsfiddle.net/DZpyw/17/show) and right clicked to save. It could be the font face thats causing it

Comment: OK, thanks, it's working now, mostly.  I have marked the question as answered.  There are two remaining issues though: 1. the text changes colour twice on hover and on leaving the div, and 2. It breaks the ability to use the text as a link, as you can see [here](http://monthlymixup.com/test.html) (should link to google).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10844/discussion-between-abstractchaos-and-nick)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
   $('a').on('hover', function( {
      $(this).css('color', getRandomColor());
     })
   );

function getRandomColor() {
  var myAwesomeColorList['#ccc', '#fff'];

  return myAwesomeColorList[Math.floor((Math.random()*myAwesomeColorList.length))]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this will only work on the whole word at once not induvidual letters