# Need to target certain number of characters with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some pages that my employer has requested that one of the titles of a tabbed page have part of the title in italic, e.g. from NewsNow to News *Now* (without the space). Problem is the pages are generated dynamically and I need to add a CSS rule. Is there a pseudo class/element I can add to the CSS to do this? Here is the template used to create the tabbed page:

```
{% block extracss %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery/jquery.ui.theme.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery/jquery.ui.core.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/jquery/jquery.ui.tabs.css' %}">
{% endblock extracss %}

{% block page_content %}
<div id="tabs">
   <ul>
     {% for tab_found in tabs_on_page %}
       <li>
          <a href="#tabs-{{ tab_found.order }}">{{ tab_found.title }}</a>
       </li>
     {% endfor %}
   </ul>
     {% for tab_found in tabs_on_page %}
<div id="tabs-{{ tab_found.order }}">
     {{ tab_found.html_blob|safe }}
</div>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
     {% endblock %}
     {% block extrajs %}
<script src="/static/core/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js">
</script>
<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#tabs").tabs();});
</script>
{% endblock extrajs %}
```

Comment: don't expect anything from CSS in this, use jQuery or JavaScript

Comment: You would need an nth-letter selector which does not exist

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, and than browser will cry for help, cuz people will start using `nth-letter` for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10429673/1542290) purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no pure CSS way to achieve that.

If you have access to the generation process you could add `<span>` tags around each part and use `span:nth-child(2)` or `span:nth-of-type(2)` to make the 2nd part *italic*

http://jsfiddle.net/pa67G/1/

Otherwise you might have to rely on a JS solution as Mr. Alien mentioned in his comment

** UPDATE **

Assuming every title consists of two parts, each starting with a capital letter, this should work as a jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pa67G/3/

It parses each title using the RegExp `([A-Z])([a-z]*)([A-Z])([a-z]*)` and replaces it wrapped by `<span>` tags.

Comment: The biggest hurdle, which I forgot to mention, is all the html is generated with Django, which I know nothing about. The person who set it up is no longer working here, so I have no way, at least that I know of, to add spans to the html. Am I SOL?

Comment: Haven't you mentioned you were using jQuery UI Tabs in an comment to another answer (that was deleted)?
Do you have access to the Django code? Maybe you can determine the generation snippet and post it here

Comment: Thanks for the snippet but it looks like it wouldn't help as well. I hope my new update will work.