# Change the 'random' to direct (queue)

Tags: javascript

```
var par = document.getElementById("rainbow");
var colors = ["1-letter", "2-letter", "3-letter", "4-letter", "5-letter", "6-letter", "7-letter", "8-letter", "9-letter"];

par.innerHTML = par.innerHTML.split('').map(function(c) {
    return "<span class='" + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)] + "'" + ">" + c + "</span>"
}).join('');
```

How can I put to get the right way just like the "colors" not as "random". To according to the queue 1-9

Comment: You probably need to use `Array.sort()`  on `par.innerHTML.split('')`.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, right now you're laboriously doing nothing to the innerHTML of 'rainbow'.  What do you want to do it?

Comment: I would like to put the css words(and color of it) in queue.

http://jsfiddle.net/cwerpxL1/

Comment: Can you draw us a picture?  Write some before-and-after HTML that shows the change you want to see.

Comment: Well, not special. I just want to put the 
.red { color: red }
.blue { color: blue }
.orange { color: orange }
.green { color: green }

In  the right queue not as a randomly.

Comment: Just like here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178217/different-letter-colors-in-a-word

Answer (score 0):

I still don't think I quite follow, but while considering your question I came up with the following little webpage, with a span of numbers that can be sorted (what I thought more your original question) and also given color according to an internal array (what I think now closer to your question).  Maybe you can adapt some of this to your task.

```
<!doctype html>
<title>random rainbow</title>

<p>These numbers are <span id=state>random</span>: <span id=numbers>213768954</span></p>

<button id=sorter>Sort</button>  <button id=styler>Style</button>

<script>
(function() {
  var state = document.getElementById('state'),
      numbers = document.getElementById('numbers'),
      sorter = document.getElementById('sorter'),
      styler = document.getElementById('styler'),
      colors =
        [ 'red', 'green', 'blue',
          'red', 'green', 'blue',
          'grey', 'magenta', 'yellow' ]

  sorter.addEventListener('click', function() {
    numbers.textContent = numbers.textContent.split('').sort().join('')
    state.textContent = 'sorted'
  })

  styler.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var i = 0, digits = numbers.textContent.split('')
    numbers.textContent = ''
    digits.forEach(function(digit) {
      var colored = document.createElement('span')
      colored.textContent = digit
      colored.style.color = colors[i++]
      numbers.appendChild(colored)
    })
  })
})()
</script>
```

Comment: Well, that's good! But could put just the result (when you clicked both of ) ? without any action

Comment: @r4nd3l8888, sure.  Just replace all of the buttons and event code with the bodies of both event listeners.

Comment: No, I meant to get the result already without any buttons and unnecessary code. Just the word with the color in queue. 
[link](http://postimg.org/image/jcgbawbg9/)