# How can I modify the line to accord to the queue?

Tags: javascript

[image: Link for the example]
As you can see I made an example what I would like to do.
It's woul be nice if it is following the var colors queue, to get exactly the same colors. Without any action button and extra function.

Comment: So you want first letter to get class `1-letter`, then second letter to get class `2-letter`, and so on?

Comment: Yes! to get the colored "example" on the image

Comment: what about [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33178340/2037556)

Comment: I need it in 1 tag :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
var par = document.getElementById("rainbow");
var colors = ["1-letter", "2-letter", "3-letter", "4-letter", "5-letter", "6-letter", "7-letter", "8-letter", "9-letter"];
var i = 0;

par.innerHTML = par.innerHTML.split('').map(function(c){
    i = (i == colors.length - 1) ? 0: i + 1;
    return "<span class='" + colors[i] + "'>" + c + "</span>";
}).join('');
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you :3

Comment: @r4nd3l8888 No problem.